Synonimize [word-order] to [syntax]?
Syntax is defined as (emphasis mine):

[...] the set of rules, principles, and processes that govern the structure of sentences (sentence structure) in a given language, usually including word order.

Currently there are 34 questions tagged word-order. I would be hard pressed to find a reason to keep the two tags separated, beside the fact that people unfamiliar with linguistics terminology maybe don't know what "syntax" means.
So the tag synonym is warranted meaning-wise, and would yield syntax if someone attempts to type "word-order" in the tag bar.
(I don't have the 5 points required to propose the synonym myself)
Thoughts?

This makes me wonder why we have both the [grammar] and [syntax] tags.  What's the difference between syntax and grammar?

We should also think what are the functionality of tags. Sometimes they might help as keywords for searches (even from within SE or from search engines like Google), so in this sense it might not really be a problem to repeat the same meaning with different words. But I agree with you that "word-order" and "syntax" seem to have the same meaning. I don't agree though about "grammar" and "syntax", as "syntax" is a subset of "grammar" (as explained in the answer of the post linked).

@Becky李蓓 will this be actioned? I don't have enough points to suggest the synonym myself

I'm not sure about this: with [grammar] ⊃ [syntax] ⊃ [word-order], why synonymize [word-order] to [syntax], instead of merging [syntax] into [grammar]?  [Edit: oops, got them backwards.]

@Becky李蓓 I agree with Puco that grammar is a superset of syntax, I wouldn't merge those. I would only merge word-order to syntax, since the two are basically equivalent and not in [syntax] ⊆ [word-order] relation. My point being: I can easily see people tagging a Q with [grammar] and not syntax, but I can't easily see this with [syntax] and [word-order]
